# How to retrieve the download and sharing link of an offline file in a OneDrive folder

Tags: c#, onedrive

Does anyone know how to get the download and sharing link of a file in a OneDrive folder?
I want to do this from Windows Desktop .NET application.
Was searching on the internet, but didn't find any hint.
I guess it must be possible in some way. If you right click on such a file in the explorer, you have the Copy Link option. How can I access that functionality from my code?

Comment: Are you wanting to use the SDK, or directly use the REST API?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. The easiest way. I have a regular filename and want to translate it to a OneDrive link.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access token it'll be pretty simple to use the REST interface to get a share link. Have a read of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn659731.aspx#get_links_to_files_and_folders.